# Calling Method From Different Form Giving Txtboxlines count zero

Tags: c#

I have a method MainTask(); which contains the below code.

```
 int i = this.textBox1.Lines.Length
```

--
I am calling the method MainTask() from different form when I called it from different form the textboxlines count is zero if I directly call the method in the same form its working fine. What is the issue?

Edit:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rankDomain.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the SERP tracking url ex:domain.com, you have 60 seconds time.");
                WaitNSeconds(60);
            }
            else
            {
                RankingsSheetName rsn = new RankingsSheetName();
                rsn.Show();
            }

        }
```

---

```
   public async void MainTask(ExcelWorksheet rankingSheet=null, ExcelPackage excelPkg=null)
            {
                int excelRowNumber = 2;
                String currentDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                //rankingSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Keyword";
                //rankingSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Featured Snippet";
                //rankingSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Comp in 1st postion";
                //rankingSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Comp in 2nd postion";
                //rankingSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Comp in 3rd postion";
                //rankingSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "SERPS";
                    int waitTime;
                    textBox1.Enabled = false;
                    btnExport.Enabled = false;
                    button2.PerformClick();
                    button2.Enabled = false;
                    d.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                    d.dataGridView1.Refresh();

                    button1.Enabled = false;
                    btnStop.Enabled = true;
                    completedkeywordsHelp.Lines = textBox1.Lines;
                    Random rnd = new Random();
    MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Lines.Length.ToString());
    }
```

---

```
public partial class RankingsSheetName : Form
    {
        public RankingsSheetName()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public ExcelWorksheet rankingSheet;
        public ExcelPackage excelPkg;

        String currentDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateExcel();
        }

        public void CreateExcel()
        {
            Form1 fm = new Form1();
            List<string> sheetNames = new List<string>();
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(currentDir + "RankingExcelFileAutoSave.xlsx");
            if (File.Exists(currentDir + "RankingExcelFileAutoSave.xlsx"))
            {
                excelPkg = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo);
                foreach (ExcelWorksheet eSheet in excelPkg.Workbook.Worksheets)
                {
                    sheetNames.Add(eSheet.ToString());
                }
            }
            int sheetSearchCount = sheetNames.Where(s => s.Equals(txtBoxSheetName.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Count();
            if (File.Exists(currentDir + "RankingExcelFileAutoSave.xlsx"))
            {
                    if (sheetSearchCount == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Name already exists in the excel file, please enter different name");
                        excelPkg.Dispose();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            rankingSheet = excelPkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(txtBoxSheetName.Text);
                            excelPkg.SaveAs(fileInfo);
                            fm.MainTask(rankingSheet, excelPkg);


                    }
            }
            else
            {
                rankingSheet = excelPkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(txtBoxSheetName.Text);
                excelPkg.SaveAs(fileInfo);
                    this.Hide();
                f.MainTask(rankingSheet, excelPkg);
            }
```

### }

I have added the more code. Please help me guys. Thank you.

Comment: You're probably looking at the wrong `TextBox`.

Comment: Nope I double checked it the textbox name is textBox1 but if I call the method with in the same form its working fine.

Comment: You have two forms or instances with the same name.

Comment: You're probably looking at the wrong `TextBox`.

Comment: Ya I have two forms but one form name is Form1 and the other one is rank_tracker

Comment: You aren't looking at the same instance.  You need to use references.  Show more of your relevant code.

Comment: I have added more code. Please look into it @LarsTech

Comment: You create a new Form1 and never show it.  You also have fm and f.  Typo?

Comment: Not a typo I modified it to test. Just neglect that f. I open that Form1 first from that form I am opening the other form RankingsSheetName.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187512/discussion-between-nav-and-larstech).